# Error with inserting value in mysql returned from mysql error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating form for adding in this case departement in my DB for my small helpdesk project.

When mysql return an error for example for duplicate item or something else, i want to insert error log in my db with returned mysql error message.

i got fallowing message from mysql: Error is Duplicate entry 'Service' for key 'name_2'.

In my code, i use session to store this error message, because i want to show this message on other page, but i cannot write this error message in my db error_log table.

I think that cause of problem is contain of '' characters i returned error message.
If i put anything else log is writen to DB.

How to remove this '' char. before i insert message in db?

Here is my code example:

```
//Attempt MySQL server connection.
    $link = mysqli_connect("$hostname_config", "$username_config", "$password_config", "$database_config");
    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    // Escape user inputs for security
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['dname']);
    $departement_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['departement_email']);
    $active = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['active']);

    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$database_config`.`ithd_user_departements` (name, departement_email, active) VALUES ('$name','$departement_email', '$active')";

    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    //Records edited successfully
    //Write sucess log
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `it_helpdesk`.`ithd_logs` (`id`, `message`, `module`, `option`, `action`, `user`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, 'Departement was inserted [ $_POST[dname] ]', '$_GET[module]', '$_GET[option]', 'Insert', '$_SESSION[loged_user]', '$date');") or die ("Error: cannot write log!"); 
    //redirect back to page
    header('Location: ?module=helpdesk&option=departements&msg=add_dep_ok');
        } else{
    //if error appear 
    //store error message in session
    $err = $link->error;
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["error_message"] = "$err";
    //write error log
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `it_helpdesk`.`ithd_error_logs` (`id`, `message`, `module`, `option`, `action`, `user`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '$_SESSION[error_message]', '$_GET[module]', '$_GET[option]', 'Insert', '$_SESSION[loged_user]', '$date');") or die ("Error: cannot write error log!");  

    //echo "Error is " . $_SESSION["error_message"] . ".";

    //redirect back to page  with error message
    header('Location: ?module=helpdesk&option=departements&msg=add_dep_error');
        }
    mysqli_close($link);
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think quotes are your current issue but you should use prepared statements with parameterized queries to fix that issue as well. You current issue is a duplicate entry, `Error is Duplicate entry` so you have made the columns values unique and are trying to insert the same value. Maybe you mean to make an update?

Comment: Another side note: it is _more_ than questionable if it is a good idea to log such errors into your database. I mean the error you deal with is an issue with your code and how it interacts with the database. To use exactly the same interface that your code obviously fails to use without issues to log the reason for the failure is like trying to use a pen that does not write to write a complaint to the producer. Error logs belong into a log file.

Comment: @arkascha, using db for logging can have lots of advantages compared to log files. What I usually do is something like `void Log(....){try {LogOnDb(); catch(){TryLogOnFile()}}` in this way I have all my logs on database (that's is convenient if you have to examine them), except the logs I cannot write because (e.g.) database server is not reachable